# Dynamic sql, how to save the result query into a new table?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, dynamic, mysql-workbench, mysql-error-1064

Below is my table structure and I want to convert it into another format (From row to column type :

```
StudentID | Mark | Subject
-------------------------
10        |46    |Java
--------------------------
10        |65    |C#
--------------------------
10        |79    |JavaScript
---------------------------
11        |66    |Java
--------------------------
11        |85    |C#
--------------------------
11        |99    |JavaScript
--------------------------
```

I need it to be like

```
StudentID | Java | C# | JavaScript
---------------------------------
10        |  46  | 65 |   79
---------------------------------
11        |  66  | 85 |  99
-------------------------------
```

I wrote a dynamic SQL query to pivot my table:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'sum(case when subject = ''',
      subject,
      ''' then mark else 0 end) AS `',
      subject, '`'
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM  yourtable;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT studentid, ', @sql, ' 
                  from yourtable
                  group by studentid');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

My question is: how to save the result into another table?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, difficult to see what you mean by that once you have corrected the all upper case text. So, better you had not given it (your edit is fine).

Answer (score 1):

For pivot results, try this:

```
select 
    StudentId,
    max(case Subject when 'Java' then Mark end) as 'Java', 
    max(case Subject when 'C#' then Mark end) as 'C#',
    max(case Subject when 'JavaScript' then Mark end) as 'JavaScript'
from
    marks_table
group by StudentId
```

To insert the output into other table, use proper syntax from `INSERT INTO ... SELECT...`.

```
insert into target_table( col1, col2, ... )
select 
    StudentId,
    max(case Subject when 'Java' then Mark end) as 'Java', 
    max(case Subject when 'C#' then Mark end) as 'C#',
    max(case Subject when 'JavaScript' then Mark end) as 'JavaScript'
from
    marks_table
group by StudentId
```

Modify the 'insert ...` and use accordingly.

---

**Edit**:

In your dynamically created query
**Change**

```
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT studentid, ', @sql, ' 
                  from yourtable
                  group by studentid');
```

**To**:

```
SET @insert_query = CONCAT( 'insert into target_table_name( ' );
SET @insert_query = CONCAT( @insert_query, 'col1, col2, col3, ... ) ' );

SET @sql = CONCAT( @insert_query, 'SELECT studentid, ', @sql, ' 
                  from yourtable
                  group by studentid');
```

---

**Edit 2**:

If you want to create a new table `pivot` from the prepared `@sql` select statement, you can use it with `create table pivot as @sql`.

**Example**:

```
set @sql := concat( 'create table pivot as ', @sql );

select @sql;

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Once you have executed above code, run the following statements to see how the column names and their data types are declared default by the sql engine.

```
mysql> desc pivot;
+------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| studentid  | int(11)       | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Java       | decimal(32,0) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| C#         | decimal(32,0) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| JavaScript | decimal(32,0) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
4 rows in set (0.08 sec)

mysql> select * from pivot;
+-----------+------+------+------------+
| studentid | Java | C#   | JavaScript |
+-----------+------+------+------------+
|        10 |   46 |   65 |         79 |
|        11 |   66 |   85 |         99 |
+-----------+------+------+------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show create table pivot\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: pivot
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `pivot` (
  `studentid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Java` decimal(32,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `C#` decimal(32,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `JavaScript` decimal(32,0) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Example** @ [**MySQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ec126/1)

Comment: If your want specific labels, then comparing strings can only be done on literals.

Comment: BTW: Please use proper sentence formats. Don't use all CAPS while asking or answering.

Comment: I din't understand .... what if there are lot of subjects ? should i write a case for all subjects ?

Comment: @joey: Just prepend the `insert into ...` to *your dynamic prepared statement*.

Comment: what if i have n number of columns ?

Comment: create table new_table SELECT //dynamic query here // should work rit?

Comment: @joey: Yes. It should be working. Your `Group_concat...` will dynamically by preparing all the columns.

Comment: create table pivoo
select
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT........ the

Comment: @joey: Can you prepare a replica of your tables and data on [*SQL Fiddle*](http://sqlfiddle.com) and let me know.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/02061/5  this is the link ... i dint create it ...its from where i got the codes .... exactly the same ..what i want

Comment: any idea ?sqlfiddle.com/#!2/02061/5 \

Comment: @joey: Yes. Check my updated answer with a demo example on SQL Fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

EDITED -> I provided an answer for MSSQL Server not MYSQL...

Ravinder is correct in his answer(voted).

Apologies, for reference if anyone comes across this on a MSSQL server:

```
SELECT * into newtable FROM
( SELECT
    StudentId,
    max(case Subject when 'Java' then Mark end) as 'Java', 
    max(case Subject when 'C#' then Mark end) as 'C#',
    max(case Subject when 'JavaScript' then Mark end) as 'JavaScript'
from
    oldtable
group by StudentId) as importvalues;
```

Comment: @joey: Nooooooo. It seems you copy pasted something else here.